# Optimization of ratio of concave and linear function

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R}_{>0} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, twice differentiable, concave, and nondecreasing. Furthermore $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L<\infty$, were $L$ is some constant. I am interested in the maximum of the function $g : \mathbb{R}_{>0} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$. Are there conditions on $g$ that guarantee a unique maximum (if it's not unbounded)? I tried to prove that if $g(x)$ has a local maximum, then it must be a global maximum. I tried this by assuming the contrary and seeking a contradiction with the concavity of $f$, but that did not work.

Comment: What does weakly concave mean?

Comment: What does weakly increasing mean?

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat, I meant nondecreasing and concave. Edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a supremum but NOT a maximum! Take $f(x)=log\dfrac{x}{x+1}$. Then $f$ satisfies all assumptions but

$g(x)=\dfrac{log\dfrac{x}{x+1}}{x}$ tends to zero as $x$ tends to infinity,

and the supremum is NOT attained by any number!! The claim about the local and global maxima is not important, since $f$ is non-decreasing. The only case when we may have a maximum is to have a constant $f$ on some $[a,+\infty)$,!! Otherwise it is not possible to have a local maximum!!

Comment: Hmm I see. But in this case the optimizer will be unbounded. Intuitively then I should be able to prove that either the optimizer is unbouded or I have a unique maximum?